# How to inherit query parameters on Link Component without knowledge of the location object

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

My App has some globally available query parameters `?from=2016-05-01&to=2016-05-7&interval=daily`

I am using react-router 2.4.0 and the `location` object is available via `props` on all of the routing components.

So whenever I am on a Component where the `location` object is available I can simply do this to keep the query params on the link:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/whatever', query: this.props.location.query }}>
   whatever
</Link>
```

By now I pass down the `location` as `prop` to all child components that need to have links with inherited query params. But I quickly realized that nearly any Component needs to know the location because I want to have the opportunity to put links anywhere. This endet up in very long prop chains.

Currently the Link Component itself does not provide an API for query inheritance, so I am wondering if anyone has a good workaround for a Link Component that can be placed anywhere but can inherit the query params!?

Update: 
I'd like to thank QoP for his answer but I forgot to mention that getting the location from the context is also no suitable solution for me, as all parent Components lose their 'pureness' which means that I can't rely on 'shallowCompare' anymore.

Comment: are you using react router 2.4.0?

Comment: Yes, updated the text :)

Comment: Are you using a flux implementation ? is your router state connected to your global state ? That could be handy to connect your nested component to a global state like the location query. Otherwise, just use `window.location.search` :)

Comment: I am using Redux. I think I have to connect the Link Wrapper to the store then. Now I really understand why context is such a bad thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an enhanced link component which automatically includes the query params.

Something like this.

```
class EnhancedLink extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
       return <Link to={{ pathname: {this.props.path}, query: this.context.location.query }}>
                 {this.props.text}
                 </Link>
    }
}

EnhancedLink.contextTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object
};


export default EnhancedLink
```

And use it like this

```
<EnhancedLink path="/yourNewUrl" text="yourLinkText" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. In my apologies I have to say that I forgot to mention that context is not a satisfying solution for me because the parent components all lose their 'pureness'. Which means that whenever I use a link in a component that has a `shallowCompare` or is connected to the `redux-store` (which does a shallowCompare too if not pure:false) the link does not get updated with the changed query params. I need to adjust my answer again :) But thanks for your input.

Comment: I will accept this answer cause I used your wrapper approach but instead of wrapping it with context I connected it to the redux store and get everything I need from the store directly. I actually don't know if it performs well but I will see...

Comment: Hey with react-router 3.0-alpha you can actually now wrap a link with 'withRouter' and still can keep your components pure because they added a new feature where you now subscribe to context changes! :)